# Traditional Spanish sorting of Strings in Java

Tags: java, sorting, locale

I'm converting a .NET application into Java. The app reads in a file with this format:

```
es-MX
jueves
verde
amarillo
blanco
llave
llover
loma
cinco
domingo
rojo
```

but I'm having a trouble figuring out how to sort Spanish according to the *traditional* sorting of words. In VB.NET, you'd do see this:

```
 Dim spainCultureTraditional As CultureInfo = New CultureInfo(&H40A)
```

but I can't find the equivalent traditional sorting locale in Java. The only difference between the two is that in `es-MX/es-ES` `llave` and `llover` would be switched versus the international sorting.

**Note:** the locale `es-ES` is not necessarily the same in Java and it is not the same in VB.NET.

Comment: I would have said that the correct thing for this is a `Collator` - but I can't get  it to work like you describe in ideone: http://ideone.com/Kf3ueO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need customised Collation rules. There is a demo for tranditional Spanish here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html

Summary code:

```
String smallnTilde = "\u00F1";
String capitalNTilde = "\u00D1";

String traditionalSpanishRules = (
    "< a,A < b,B < c,C " +
    "< ch, cH, Ch, CH " +
    "< d,D < e,E < f,F " +
    "< g,G < h,H < i,I < j,J < k,K < l,L " +
    "< ll, lL, Ll, LL " +
    "< m,M < n,N " +
    "< " + smallnTilde + "," + capitalNTilde + " " +
    "< o,O < p,P < q,Q < r,R " +
    "< s,S < t,T < u,U < v,V < w,W < x,X " +
    "< y,Y < z,Z");

RuleBasedCollator spCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(traditionalSpanishRules);

Collections.sort(words, spCollator);
System.out.println(words);
```

Comment: When using this code, please remove the calls to `new String`. It’s a shame that the official Java documentation suggests it, but there’s no reason to do that in your own code.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I edited the code and removed them. I think that wouldn't allow these strings to be interned.

Comment: Much obliged! It worked like a charm - better yet, it makes perfect sense why it works.