# Processing text which contains double-leterred 'character'

Tags: java, frequency-analysis, alphabet

How would you treat/store letter 'CH' in java code for let's say frequency analysis? I haven't found any alphabet libraries that will work with the double lettered 'CH'. Storing in char is no longer an option. All the text processing algorithms just scans one by one. But now I will need to somehow scan ahead to match the pair. There is no 'CH' char in unicode either, are there any other coding tables where 'CH' can be found?

Another way will be to replace 'CH' with '1' in input data files and treat the '1' as another regular character. By which I will loose the option of ASCII codes aritmetics('a' - 't' is nonsense as the 'ch' is missing in ASCII)

Comment: A... uh... string?

Comment: I'm afraid it's really unclear what your requirement is. One time I read the question, I thought "he/she needs a `Map`". Another time, I thought "he/she needs the phonetic alphabet." The third time...I just don't know. :-)

Comment: The thing is how would you analyze text which contains 'ch' letter. Of course I can use List of Strings to represent the alphabet. But I will need to write everything by myself. Checking if there is another options how to work with it. It is about 'ch' which is regular letter in czech alphabet. For example 'KOI-8 CS2' treats it as single character, but how to utilize this knowledge in java.

Comment: You would need to invent your own number scheme for things you want to count. Then convert character sequences from input to this scheme and then do the frequency analysis.

Comment: If you are thinking of Spanish, be aware of the history of "ch" in the [alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography#Alphabet_in_Spanish). Also see [Traditional Spanish sorting of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36947700/2226988).

Comment: Maybe a [StringCharacterIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) with the right locale?

Comment: @TomBlodget locale won't help as the 'ch' is two chars, it is not special char. It is kind of confusing. Everything boils down to replace 'ch' with either another random  ASCII char or convert it to mentioned coding table, but not sure how to do it in java especially with such obscure coding table.

Comment: The 'KOI-8-CS2' treats 'ch' an 'CH' as single char, but anyway they have not the proper ordinal, so the aritmetics will not work. I will now just replace all 'CH' by something and map it back when presenting the results.

Comment: For processing, I would just use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, with the key being the [normalized](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html), "extended grapheme cluster" (including [digraphs](https://www.unicode.org/faq/ligature_digraph.html#Dig1)) with joiners stripped out. Then, on reporting, perhaps collapse case differences. It's very frustrating for "ch" because it is apparently in the [LCDR](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/34/summary/cs.html) as a Czech letter (in order). Perhaps the version used by Java isn't up-to-date and perhaps ICU4J would do better.